# virtualenv with --always-copy throws error "Operation not permitted"

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm trying to run virtualenv without symlinking python2.7 but I get permission errors when I use the flag --always-copy.

```
virtualenv --always-copy myenv

Traceback (most recent call last):  

  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>  
    sys.exit(main())  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 711, in main  
    symlink=options.symlink)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 924, in create_environment  
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1129, in install_python  
    copyfile(join(stdlib_dir, fn), join(lib_dir, fn), symlink)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 355, in copy file  
    copyfileordir(src, dest, symlink)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 327, in copyfileordir  
    shutil.copytree(src, dest, symlink)  
  File   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree  
    raise Error, errors  
shutil.Error:  
[('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/config.c', '/Users/user1/myenv/lib/python2.7/config/config.c', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/user1/myenv/lib/python2.7/config/config.c'"), ...
```

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the directory you are in?  What does `ls -la` tell you?

Comment: I just stumbled over the same problem. Root access is not an issue: I can read the source files and I can also manually perform the cp command. I get the same files as problematic. :/

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787331/4201810).

Answer (score -1):

Hard to answer without additional details but my guess would be you need to sudo first.

so `sudo virtualenv --always-copy myenv`