# Unable to setup virtualenv with '--always-copy' flag due to Errno 1

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to run this command

```
$ virtualenv --always-copy venv
```

Then I got all these errors:

```
        shutil.Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Drag.so', 
'/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Drag.so', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
 '/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Drag.so'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Ctl.so', 
'/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Ctl.so', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 
'/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Ctl.so'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/imageop.so', 
'/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/imageop.so', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 
'/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/imageop.so'"), 
('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Scrap.so', 
'/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Scrap.so', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 
'/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Scrap.so'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_testcapi.so', 
'/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_testcapi.so', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 
'/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_testcapi.so'"), 
('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so', 
'/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so'"),
```

I checked the permission of the source file. It  is all readable

```
$ ls -l '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Drag.so'
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  55936  3 Oct 16:50 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Drag.so
```

I have always ensured venv does not exist before running the command.

So why the failure?

Version info:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

virtualenv use `shutil.copytree` to copy files, `copytree` will copy src file flags to destination with `copystat`, but the macOS system python files have a special flag `0x80000`, which can not set by a normal user, even root.

if you installed a python with homebrew, which does not have this flag, this command would work.

---

Update:

according to [stat.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3789.70.16/bsd/sys/stat.h.auto.html) `0x80000` is `SF_RESTRICTED`:

```
#define SF_RESTRICTED   0x00080000  /* restricted access */
```

it is something new with Yosemite System Integrity Protection.

you could see `restricted` flag in with `ls -lO` output:

```
$ ls -lO '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Drag.so'
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted,compressed 55888 Jul 15 12:21 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_Drag.so
```

if you try to set it in the command line:

```
$ sudo chflags restricted tmp
chflags: tmp: Operation not permitted
```

I think python `shutil.copystat` should exclude this flag as there is no way to set it in userland without special entitlement assigned by Apple.